# Check if grid has aggregate

Tags: grid, jqwidget

Is there a way in jQWidgets Grid to know if a certain grid has an aggregated row or not?

I have a problem in the following code :

```
var temp = $(gridId).jqxGrid('getcolumnaggregateddata', columnFields[i], ['sum']);
```

I want to check first if there's an aggregate in the grid before I call the above code.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your jqxgrid had 'showaggregates' property with true value or not

```
if( $("#" + gridId).jqxGrid('showaggregates') ) {
    // there is...
}
else {
    // there is not...
}
```